# How to make an average from values of a foreign key in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a book model and a review model like this in Django:

```
class Book(models.Model):

    ratings = models.FloatField()


class Review(models.Model):
    book = models.ForeignKey(
        Book,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='reviews',
    )
    review = models.CharField(max_length=5000)
    score = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(null=True, blank=True,
                                             validators=[MinValueValidator(0), MaxValueValidator(10)])
```

How can I create a method in Book to calculate the ratings (which is the average from all Reviews associated to a specific book)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can implement a property like:

```
from django.db.models import Avg

class Book(models.Model):

    @property
    def ratings(self):
        return self.reviews.aggregate(avg_score=Avg('score'))['avg_score']
```

Or if you need to do this in *bulk*, you can annotate your queryset:

```
from django.db.models import Avg

Book.objects.annotate(
    avg_rating=Avg('reviews__score')
)
```

`Book` objects that arise from this queryset, will have an extra attribute `avg_rating`, that contains the average of the `score` of the related `Review`s.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Which one is more efficient? This calculates it every time, right? I'll probably have to cache it... which one do you think is better for that? The one in bulk?

Comment: @S.D.: the first one calculates it every time yes, and makes one query *per* `Book`. The latter calculates all the average reviews for all the `Book`s in the queryset in the *same* query. So if you want to display the average reviews of a medium-large amount of books, the latter is better, since it avoids an *N+1 problem*.

Comment: Thanks. Where is best practice to put the code of the second solution, in models.py?

Comment: @S.D: no, in the views where you need the average rating of the `Book`s.

Comment: if you need to retrieve the rating every time you retrieve the book I guess the best approach is creating a new 'rating' field in the Book model and every time a new review is created update that value, or whats best in that case? @WillemVanOnsem

Comment: @Brechard: no, annotate. Using a field means you introduce *data duplication*. It turns out that keeping data in sync is a hard problem, even if the data is stored on the same database. For example if you *create* a review, if you *delete* a review, if you *edit* a review, assign a review to a different `Book`, sometimes the removal of a `Review` can be triggered by cascading `ForeignKey`s, for example when you remove all the `Review`s of a user, so it is easy to forget a case, and eventually the average will run out of sync.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem ah ok makes sense thanks! But isn't annotating the whole Book table every time that a book information is retrieved inefficient? or is it a standard procedure?

Comment: @Brechard: typically you paginate it if there is a large number of elements, and a database works with indexes to make retrieving the related `Review`s more efficient than just linear search.